# Orbits of $z_{n+1} = z_n ^2 - 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the sequence $z_{n+1} = z_n ^2 - 1$ defined for an arbitrary complex number $z_0$. I am trying to determine all $z_0$ such that the sequence eventually becomes periodic.

Here is my progress so far:

If $|z_0|> \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ the sequence is absolutely increasing since
$$|z_{n+1}|=|z_n^2 - 1|\geq|z_n|^2-1 > |z_n| ,$$
which is true since $ |z_n| > \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ holds inductively.

If $z_0=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ the sequence would be the constant sequence of $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and hence periodic.

Similar to the first case if $|z_0|<\frac{1}{2}$ or more precisely if $|z_0|$ less than the root of $\alpha^3 +2\alpha -1 = 0,$ the sequence $\{z_{2i} \}$ becomes strictly decreasing since
$$|z_{2i}| = |z_{2i-1}^2 - 1 |= |z_{2i-2}^4 - 2z_{2i-2}^2|<  |z_{2i-2}| \Leftrightarrow |z_{2i-2}^3 - 2z_{2i-2}| < 1.$$
Which holds true if
$$ |z_{2i-2}^3 - 2z_{2i-2}| \leq  |z_{2i-2}^3|+| 2z_{2i-2}| <1.$$
And as a result $\{z_i\}$ cannot be periodic.

Comment: This is a question about the Julia set of $z \mapsto z^2-1$: if you haven't come across that term, you should look it up first. Pretty fractals!

Comment: See a picture at https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/Julia-1.png

Comment: Even more fun to look at video zooms of fractals. https://youtu.be/YOneAeBz8BQ

Comment: How is the absolute values converging to some value not indicate a period result? The absolute values are still non-negative, so decreasing doesn’t mean not converging.

Comment: In theory, increasing doesn’t mean it isn’t periodic, either, but the sequence is increasing exponentially, which is why the increasing case does not converge to a periodic sequence.

Comment: When $|z_0|<1/2, $ the sequence actually converges to the periodic $0,-1,0,-1,\dots.$

Comment: Specifically, each attracting periodic point is in the interior of one of those red blobs, and each red blob has one attracting periodic point in its interior. The repulsive periodic points are dense in the boundary between red and green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us find the alternative solutions.

Firstly, let us consider the case of the exact periodicity.

Assuming the periods $1,2,3,\dots,$ easily to get

- $z=z^2-1,\quad z_{11}=\phi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2,\quad z_{12}=-\dfrac1\phi=\dfrac{1-\sqrt5}2;$
- $z=(z^2-1)^2-1,\quad z(z+1)(z^2-z-1)=0,$

$\qquad z_{21}=z_{11},\quad z_{22}=z_{12},\quad z_3=0,\quad z_4=1;$

- $z=((z^2-1)^2-1)^2-1,\quad (z^2-z-1)(z^6+z^5-2z^4-z^3+z^2+1)=0$

$\qquad z_{31}=z_{11},\quad z_{32}=z_{12},$
$\quad z_{33,34}\approx -1.42203\pm 0.114188i,\quad z_{35,36}\approx-0.0871062\pm0.655455i,\quad z_{37,38}=1.00914\pm0.324759i;$

- $\dots$

Also, the roots of the equations
$$z^2-1=z_{mn},$$
$$((z^2-1)^2-1)=z_{mn},\dots$$
leads to the required sequences.